# develop an android program to scan an apk file

Tags: java, android, security, apk, rsa

I want to develop an android program to scan and retrieve package name and developer digital certificate/fingerprint from an apk file which resides in the local file system. I am new to android programming and I have already figured a method to browse the file system and locate a file. However, I need to how to retrieve developer fingerprint **using an android program**. The digital certificate resides in the **META-INF** folder as **CERT.RSA** in the **APK**.

Comment: stackoverflow is not for develop a program for you..... please share what you have tried so far by your self....

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) to see the structure of the .RSA file. I think the signature is the last 256 bytes, but I am not 100% sure.
Keep in mind that the name of the file is not always CERT.RSA; it may be ANYTHING.RSA